# Can't access network login page

Tags: networking, linux-mint, networkmanager

I have a ethernet cable connection to my university's network, and I've been using it regularly and without a problem for months now. 2 days ago suddenly it stopped working. now I can only access subdomains of the website *.ut.ac.ir and ut.ac.ir except the login page which is internet.ut.ac.ir

when I use ping on internet.ut.ac.ir it says destination host unreachable.
But this happens only on my linux mint operating system. I have windows and ubuntu too, and those are working smoothly and as expected.

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1:
I ran a traceroute on internet.ut.ac.ir and ems.ut.ac.ir and here is the result:

```
traceroute internet.ut.ac.ir traceroute to internet.ut.ac.ir (172.17.49.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets  
1  arianhf-Lenovo-Z50-70 (172.17.0.1)  725.530 ms !H  725.507 ms !H  725.493 ms !H

traceroute ems.ut.ac.ir     
traceroute to ems.ut.ac.ir (192.168.112.132), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (172.18.47.129)  0.385 ms  0.781 ms  0.957 ms
 2  192.168.40.1 (192.168.40.1)  1.063 ms  1.132 ms  1.191 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
...
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

EDIT 2:
this is the output of the command when I use university network:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.18.47.129   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp1s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 docker0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.47.128   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     100    0        0 enp1s0
```

this is the output of the same command connected to my phone with USB

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.20.10.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s20u3c4i2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 docker0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.20.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     100    0        0 enp0s20u3c4i2
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first check iptables or firewall on your mint linux. Next check the network routes and the last thing you should test is DNS resolving server configuration.

Comment: ok, so how should i do that? what should I look for?

Comment: @arianhf Do you ping reply on windows?

Comment: I added some more info, also I have turned all kinds of firewalls off @P.Goli

Comment: @arianhf Would you please copy the output of route -n command?

Comment: I added that info as an edit.

Comment: Wish you were share your experience with us!